# Default Firebase reset password email generates a malformed URL

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-identity

I'm trying to reset the password for a Firebase (with Identity Platform) user. I am getting the email, but the URL for the link is missing everything before the `?` (this is true for both the text and the link href). See below for a slightly scrubbed version of the email.

```
Follow this link to reset your project-xyz password for your xyz@xyz.com account.

?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=xyz_xyzOIePvQiIn51vggJ_EWUz95iV58PxyzsEnVC8AAAGKWwExyz&apiKey=totallyrealkey&lang=en

If you didn’t ask to reset your password, you can ignore this email.
```

I've tried sending the email from both the Firebase console and the Identity Platform console. I got emails with bad URLs both times. I haven't customized the template and the relevant line looks like this in the console:

```
<p><a href='%LINK%'>%LINK%</a></p>
```